# Well-intending user repeatedly adds wrong tag, what do I do?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to contact a user to let them know their suggested edits are partially wrong](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/918/how-to-contact-a-user-to-let-them-know-their-suggested-edits-are-partially-wrong)

A certain well meaning community member has recently taken the time to edit questions and add more relevant tags.

This in itself is great, as the tags are generally relevant and well chosen, and I've simply accepted a number of edits.

However, this same person also insists on slapping the [7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7)-tag onto essentially every single question, even though the description of the tag clearly states that it should *not* be used

> just to report "I am using Drupal 7 in my site."

which is frequently the case, since "everyone" uses D7 to build sites today.

Other than 'improving' the edits further by removing the [7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7)-tag again, what can I do?

I wish that there was a drupal.org style "personal contact form" on this site, but as far as I know, there isn't.

I *could* make a comment on any question/answers posted by the user just to get a notification sent over, but that's a, "hack", so to speak.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, is *'"everyone" uses D7 to build sites today'* really true? I wish it was true, but I keep seeing D6 sites on the Drupal.org 'Sites made with Drupal' feed, and I keep reading blog articles from high-turnover Drupal agencies who still, in late 2012, use D6 for 90% of their sites and D7 only for very simple sites or sites highly reliant on custom modules. I hope I'm wrong and the tide has finally turned...

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but I have absolutely no idea how that is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@-referring a user works also for who edits a post. The username will not autocomplete when you write it, but the user will be notified of the comment you left her/him. Just remind you need to write at least 3 characters; if the username has a space, don't write it.

It's enough you write a comment for an edit. If the user keeps added not necessary tags, you can start reject her/his edits. If other users reject the edits too, the user will not be able to suggest edits for a week.